# How to stop Visual Studio from asking if I want to save a solution file every time I make adhoc changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013

At present I'm working on a project that involves lots of little changes across a lot of files in source control (TFS). I'll open the file in Visual Studio via Source Control Explorer, make my change and check it in, but every single time I go to check it in Visual Studio asks me if I want to save the solution file it's automatically created. The options here are "Yes", where I have to create a solution file I don't want, or "No" and it doesn't let me check my file in. The only way around it is to close the solution (that I never wanted to create in the first place) before checking the file in. This behavior is a real nuisance and slows me down. I just want to make my change and check my file in. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

From Visual Studio Tools menu, select "Options", then "Projects and Solutions". Uncheck the option "Always show solution".

[image]

This will still create a solution file for you when you close your project but will not prompt you.

Comment: That didn't work - I still get prompted to save a solution when I go to check my files in.

Comment: You are right. That worked when I close the Visual Studio window but not when I attempt to check-in. Don't see any other way of avoiding it I am afraid. 

You can use the tf.exe command using /noprompt switch.

Comment: I've been using the trick for years, but now in VS 2019 the option is not present any more. Any ideas where it has gone or what else can be done?